# C# Optimizing mass enum comparison

Tags: c#, optimization, enums, comparison

Is there a way to optimize the following code:

```
enum ObjType
{
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D,
    E,
    F,
    G,
    H
}
...
if (instance.ObjType == ObjType.B
    || instance.ObjType == ObjType.D
    || instance.ObjType == ObjType.E
    || instance.ObjType == ObjType.F
    || instance.ObjType == ObjType.G
    || instance.ObjType == ObjType.H)
    doSmth();
```

The following solution will not suit me:

```
if (instance.ObjType >= ObjType.B)
    doSmth();
```

because different situations require mass comparison of different combinations of ObjType.

Comment: What do you mean by optimized?  Do you want it to run faster?  Or are you looking for cleaner easier to read code?  I don't think there is much you can do about the former and what you have should suit for the latter.  In fact I'd only recommend changing this if you do this same comparison in a lot of different places.

Comment: I am looking for speed. In our engine, comparisons similar to this are run in many places. Every such comparison has a different set of ObjType-s to check against.

Comment: Well technically if you put the comparisons in order from the most likely to the least then it would be more "optimized", but I doubt you'd see much of a difference.  When optimizing you should profile your code and find the bottle necks.  Have you identified this as a bottle neck?  Don't guess what needs optimized or you could end up wasting time trying to optimize something that doesn't need to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define the enum as flags enum

```
[Flags]
enum ObjType
{
    None = 0,
    A = 1 << 0,
    B = 1 << 1,
    C = 1 << 2,
    D = 1 << 3,
    E = 1 << 4,
    F = 1 << 5,
    G = 1 << 6,
    H = 1 << 7,
    MyCombination1 = A | B | D,
    MyCombination2 = C | F | G | H
}
```

Like this you can define up to 32 values (plus `None = 0` and any number of combinations of other values) or up to 64 values with

```
[Flags]
enum ObjType : long
{
    None = 0,
    A = 1L << 0,
    B = 1L << 1,
    ...
}
```

Now you can compare

```
if (instance.ObjType & ObjType.MyCombination1 != ObjType.None) {
   ...
}
```

---

You can also define constants outside of the enum itself, if it better suits your needs

```
private const ObjType AdHocCombination = ObjType.A | ObjType.C | ObjType.H;
```

---

When defining flags, the values must have powers of two (except for `None`). This is easily achieved by using the left shift operator `<<`.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Your code should be faster than mine right?

Comment: Surely it is (derp :)), it's a single operation versus multiple ones. I am choosing your answer as it is more informative than dasblinkenlight's one.

Comment: In any case my code requires only one bitwise and-operation and one comparison and will be the fastest possible.

Comment: Oliver, but is there a way to define more than 64 values? And one more thing: does it matter if the values don't go one after another? I mean 1 << 0, 1 << 3, 1 << 31?

Comment: And one more question: what do I need to change if I'm checking for instance.ObjType != ObjType... instead of "==". Just check for instance.ObjType & ObjType.MyCombination1 == ObjType.None?

Comment: Oliver, you have missed on an important info in your answer - when you use enum : long, you have to assign values to elements in a specific way: instead of A = 1 << 0, you should write A = (long)1 << 0. Please edit your answer.

Comment: You cannot define more than 64 values, because flag values always set one bit of binary representation of an integer number. If you need more values, use `HashSet<ObjType>` together with a non-flag enums. The order of the values does not matter; however they must be powers of 2 (1, 2, 4, 8, 16 ...), since they represent the bits mentioned before. Either check if the flag is in the combination with `instance.ObjType & ObjType.MyCombination1 != ObjType.None` or check if it is *not* in it with `instance.ObjType & ObjType.MyCombination1 == ObjType.None`. Added info to the `long` example.

Answer (score 2):

If you assign the values manually, like this

```
enum ObjType
{
    A = 1,
    B = 2,
    C = 3,
    ...
    H = 8
}
```

you would be able to use numeric comparisons.

Similarly, if you use enum flags you would be able to use bit masking:

```
[Flags]
enum ObjType
{
    A = 1,
    B = 2,
    C = 4,
    ...
    H = 256
}

if (((ObjType.A | ObjType.B | ObjType.C) & val) != 0) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Will this be faster than the original code? I am looking for speed. And I cannot understand how this code is equal to mine? Does "val" mean "instance.ObjType" in your code?

Comment: @cubrman The answers to both your questions are yes and yes. This will be faster because OR-ing will be done at compile time, so the comparison at runtime will be done in just two operations with no branches.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, there's nothing wrong with your code. It's idiomatic C#.

If, by "optimize", you mean "get rid of all the redundancy", I would suggest the following:

```
var relevantTypes = new[] { ObjType.B, ObjType.D, ObjType.E, ... };

if (relevantTypes.Contains(instance.ObjType))
    doSmth();
```

The local variable is just an example, personally, I'd make it a `private static readonly` field (since you cannot have a `const` array).

If you choose the name wisely, this will also make your code self-documenting:

```
if (FooableTypes.Contains(instance.ObjType))
    doSmth();

if (TypesComparableToBar.Contains(instance.ObjType))
    doSmthElse();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do that comparison a lot and you are looking to make it more readable then one possible solution would be an extension method

```
public static IsBDEFGH(this ObjType oType)
{
    return oType == ObjType.B
        || oType == ObjType.D
        || oType == ObjType.E
        || oType == ObjType.F
        || oType == ObjType.G
        || oType == ObjType.H;
}
```

Then use it like

```
if(instance.ObjType.IsBDEFGH())
{
}
```

Pick a good name that will make it clear what values are being compared.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your need you can use `[Flags]` as follow :

```
[Flags]
enum ObjType 
{
    SomethingSpecial = 1 << 0,
    SomethingSpecialElse = 1 << 1,

    A = (1 << 16),
    B = (1 << 17) | ObjType.SomethingSpecial,
    C = (1 << 18) | ObjType.SomethingSpecialElse,
    D = (1 << 19) | ObjType.SomethingSpecial | ObjType.SomethingSpecialElse,
}
```

You can then use the `HasFlag` method :

```
    ObjType.A.HasFlag(ObjType.SomethingSpecial);        // false
    ObjType.A.HasFlag(ObjType.SomethingSpecialElse);    // false
    ObjType.B.HasFlag(ObjType.SomethingSpecial);        // true
    ObjType.B.HasFlag(ObjType.SomethingSpecialElse);    // false
    ObjType.C.HasFlag(ObjType.SomethingSpecial);        // false
    ObjType.C.HasFlag(ObjType.SomethingSpecialElse);    // true
    ObjType.D.HasFlag(ObjType.SomethingSpecial);        // true
    ObjType.D.HasFlag(ObjType.SomethingSpecialElse);    // true
```